# Alternative conditional statement to "count" in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I have a aws resource that i only want to be built in the production environment. Usually i would use something like this:

```
count = var.environment == "production" ? 1 : 0
```

However, as per the terraform documentation, count is not supported when used in a module for versions of terraform lower than 13. ("[Module support for count was added in Terraform 0.13, and previous versions can only use it with resources](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count).")

I am using terraform 12 and the resource is coming from a module and so I would like a different conditional statement that will only build the resource in production but not sure what else there is other than the count function

Comment: There is no alternative. You have to upgrade your TF

Comment: If you are set on not upgrading ... You could pass the statement as a variable and then let the resources inside the module use it on a count. (that assumes you have full access to the module code)

Comment: Thanks @HelderSepulveda ! yeah i got full access to the module. Would you mind explaining what you mean a bit more? Not sure how i would pass the above statement as a variable

Answer (score 2):

Here is more details on my comments:

Here is my test module "policies", code is something like:

```
variable "foo" {
  type = number
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "policy_abc" {
  count = var.foo
  ...
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "policy_def" {
  count = var.foo
  ...
}
```

calling the module

```
module "bar" {
  source = "../modules/policies"

  foo = var.environment == "production" ? 1 : 0
  ...
}
```